What is the risk factor of exposure to radon gas?
This site's answer to Acute symptoms from radon gas exposure provides a very good description of the process by which radon gas can cause lung cancer.
But it doesn't provide specific risk values.
We know that:

Each atom individually and independently creates a risk.
There is no cumulative effect.
There is no exposure threshold where risk begins.
The overall risk increases linearly with exposure time and with radon concentration.

So, given a risk factor for any specific exposure, one could calculate the risk at any other exposure level.
For instance, if exposure for 1 year at 100 Bq/m³ causes a risk of 1 additional instance of lung cancer per N people, then 2 years at 300 Bq/m³ would cause a risk of 6 additional instances of lung cancer per N people.
The problem is, I haven't been able to find what the value of N is (not necessarily for the specific 1 and 100 values in the example).
What is the value of N?

Those "things we know" aren't quite true, or at least are a bit misleading; I don't see those claims in the source you link.
Very generally, cancer happens when you've accumulated "enough" mutations in a particular cell, not just one, and the damage needs to happen before that cell dies some other way. So, each atom individually and independently causes a risk for some DNA damage, but it's not true that there's no cumulative effect for cancer.
From https://www.epa.gov/radon/health-risk-radon#head "Radon Risk If You Have Never Smoked" per 1000 people:

20 pCi/L (740 Bq/m3)  About 36 people could get lung cancer
10 pCi/L (370 Bq/m3)  About 18 people could get lung cancer
4 pCi/L (150 Bq/m3)   About 7 people could get lung cancer

...etc. Fairly linear at these exposure levels for non-smokers.
"Radon risk if you smoke:" (again, per 1000)

20 pCi/L (740 Bq/m3)  About 260 people could get lung cancer
10 pCi/L (370 Bq/m3)  About 150 people could get lung cancer
4 pCi/L (150 Bq/m3)   About 62 people could get lung cancer

Not quite as linear, and not additive with the numbers above: this isn't "radon risk plus smoking risk", it's more complicated than that. There are some people who will have gotten cancer just from smoking without any exposure to radon at all; there are others who you might think of as "at the threshold" for cancer where just a little more exposure to risk causes that one more mutation necessary for a given cell to become cancerous.
There's also the issue of odds versus rates here: every person who gets cancer becomes a person who can't get counted again as having cancer, so your denominator of "people at risk" shrinks as you get closer to 1000.
These are lifetime numbers. Again, it's difficult to extrapolate to a "per year" number because of expected non-linearities: chances of cancer are also going to go up substantially as you age because of accumulated mutations. The 1-year risk of a small dose of radiation for a 20 yr old is going to be very different than the 1-year risk of a small dose for an 80 yr old.
